# Facebook share - display wrong image

Tags: angular, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, angular-universal

I have problem with display image while sharing link:

https://digital.nbbd.me/unit/zorica-joksimovic-from-water-and-stone-to-story-and-storytelling

Title and description display correct, but image not.
When I try with debug tool, it warns that og:image parameters are missing, but they appears in source code. Also, in debug, image is displayed correctly.
However, when I share it, it display logo image, not the one which is in code.
I would appreciate any advice how to solve it.
Project is made in Angular, also using Angular Universal.

Comment: can  you also provide code snippets above?

Comment: The debug tool does not only complain about the missing image, but if you click "show all warnings", it also shows _“Missing Properties: The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description”_ - so, it did not recognize _any_ of your OG meta data. You got these tags starting from line 523 in your source code - try placing them higher up, Facebook expects to see them more towards the beginning of the document, rather than buried way down somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is not set correctly:

```
<meta _ngcontent-sc324="" property="og:url" content="">
```

Also, make sure to put your OG tags before any CSS or JS, Facebook does not parse the whole Page.

Sidenote: Not sure if it is normal in Angular, but you have 2 html tags, 2 head tags and 2 body tags in your source. Either way, make sure to put the OG tags in the main head section.

Comment: That's weid I can see the correct content: `<meta _ngcontent-sc324="" property="og:image" content="https://digital.nbbd.me/static/dl-unit/im/from-water-digital-1-m.jpg"`.  But the double `head` and `body` is probably the source of the error

Comment: it is not about the og:image, check my answer: og:title is the problem. it must be set correctly too, or facebook might not know where to get the data from.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice duplication of html tags html, head and body so will first correct that part and continue according your suggestion.